# What os does the os module in Python use?

Tags: python, module

Basically, would the os module installed on a Unix system use the Unix command line, or would it be standardized across all operating systems that can use Python? If so, what type of os does it use?

Comment: the `os` module abstracts the details of your particular operating system. It probably has some differences in behaviour on different OS's (I'm not a Python expert, but the library documentation should mention any of these), but the general point is to allow you to interact with whatever OS it runs on, without the developer having to know the precise details.

Comment: The os module is an abstracted way to access things that relate to the OS, potentially by using OS-specific APIs underneath. It doesn't have an OS embedded into it and it won't be using the command line to run things.

Comment: The one Python is running on — it doesn't use the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PyMOTW3](https://pymotw.com/3/os/index.html) regarding `os` module states that

> The os module provides a wrapper for platform specific modules such as
> posix, nt, and mac. The API for functions available on all platforms
> should be the same, so using the os module offers some measure of
> portability. Not all functions are available on every platform,
> however. Many of the process management functions described in this
> summary are not available for Windows.

So do not expect it will work at any *operating systems that can use Python* unless you use subset of it common for different operating systems.